# Symfony 4 - Best Practice with private external service

Tags: service, external, private, public, symfony4

I've install last version of Symfony 4 and it's rocks !

But i've got a question when we use external private service in your controller what is the better way :

For exemple i've got jwt service manager which is private; I can't call this service directly in my controller because i've got this error :

```
The "lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead."
```

**Solution 1:**

i create a public JWTService like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Service\JWT;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class JwtService
 * @package App\Service\JWT
 */
class JwtService
{
    /**
     * @var $JwtManager
     */
    private $JwtManager;

    public function __construct(JWTTokenManagerInterface $JwtManager)
    {
        $this->JwtManager = $JwtManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function create(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->JwtManager->create($user);
    }
}
```

To call this class in my controller

**Solution 2 :**

I inject 'lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager' in my controller service and i use this service by constructor :

```
services:
   app.controller.user:
       class: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
        arguments:
            - '@lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager'
```

And in my controller i use this service like this

```
class UserController extends Controller {

  private $jwt;

  public function __construct(JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwt) {
    $this->jwt = $jwt;
  }

  public function myAction() {
    // $this->jwt->...
  }
}
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I have the same questions here

Answer (score 3):

Injection (2 option). Autowiring will handle it. Avoid access the container as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks it's was my thought, force to do to not big controller ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 3 :**

```
    public function myAction(JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwt) {
    // $jwt->...   
}
```

@Jorge do you thin it's a good pratice ?

Thx.

Comment: Could be for some use cases but I'll avoid this as much as possible